# Find equation for surface area of ellipse projected on a sphere

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

A grad school problem has been haunting me for years and I have never been able to find it on the google machine nor was the professor who assigned the problem able to describe how to actually solve the problem...

How do you find the surface area of an ellipse projected onto a sphere?

The real world application is what is the footprint area of a satellite transmission signal so you know how long a ground station will be in contact with the satellite?

Comment: Two things are needed to clarify.  Firstly, wanna find an area of which?  Ellipsoid or sphere?  Secondly, what kind of projection is?  Say from a point, parallel beam or one inscribed by the other?

Comment: How is the ellipse projected onto the sphere? Central projection towards the center of the earth? Central projection from the position of the satellite? Parallel projection? In what form do you have the ellipse defined? Can you provide a concrete example, which users should use and which would allow answers to be compared against each other?